# how do i use hovering slide images on notepad++?

Tags: html, css, slider, position, overflow

I started a project in Notepad++ and I would like to create a slider on hover while using CSS. 
 The problem is that I do not know if my picture (which I wanted to create a slider with) needs to be separated in 2 images or 1 merged picture.
 I also don't know if `translate3d` works in notepad++.

Here's what my HTML looks like:

```
<div class="college">
<img src="image.png" />
```

and here's my current CSS:

```
body {
  background: url("anotherimage.png") 33em 0% fixed no-repeat;
  background-color: rgb(0,85,170); 
}

.college  {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 325px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.college img {

}

.college img:hover {

}
```

*edit*

hello again, after we've found out about my problem with hovering sliding images, i managed to make my own ligns of codes but now im stuck into another problem, while i was douing my code my images were going behind the background which i liked it very much but when i finished all of it, it stopped douing it ,i've tried using overflow: hidden and postion: absolute but i don't really get how it works especially since when i search what their fonction does. and i thought i was douing right but it seems it doesn't change anything at all,

so i would like to know how i manage to make my moving pictures to go out of the screen/ hide inside the background.

here what my css looks like

```
 ` .college .image  {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 475px;
  position: absolute

 }
.college .imagesecond {
 transform: translate(0px,500px);
 transition: transform 1s ease-in-out 0.2s;
 border-radius: 8px;

 overflow: hidden

}
.college:hover > .imagesecond{
 transform: translate(0,-200px);
}

.lycee .image { 
margin-left: 700px;
margin-top: 500px;
position: absolute
}
.lycee .imagefourth{
transform: translate(0px,500px);
transition: transform 0.9s ease-in-out 0.2s;
border-radius: 8px;
overflow: hidden
}
.lycee:hover > .imagefourth{
transform: translate(0,-500px);
}
.formation .image{
margin-left: 1250px;
margin-top:510px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.formation .imagesixth{
transform: translate(0px,100px);
transition: transform 1s ease-in-out 0.2s;
 border-radius: 8px;
overflow: hidden
}
.formation:hover > .imagesixth{
 transform: translate(0 ,-75
 0px);`
```

here is my html

```
<div class="saintemarie">
        <a href="">
            <div class="college">
                <img class="image imagefirst" src="choixcollege.png" />
                <img class="image imagesecond" src="pepepls.gif"/>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="lyceesaintemarie.html">
            <div class="lycee">
                <img class="image imagethird" src="choixlyceepro.png" />
                <img class="image imagefourth" src="pepepls.gif" />
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="c&fsaintemarie.html">
            <div class="formation">
                <img class="image imagefifth" src="choix 
                 centre&formation.png" />
                <img class="image imagesixth" src="pepepls.gif" />
            </div>
            </div>  
        </a
```

Comment: CSS doesn't get rendered in notepad++. The browser is what supports or doesn't support CSS properties. Check out https://caniuse.com/ to see which properties are supported in your browser and which are not.

Comment: "translate3d on notepad++" >>> dafuq i just got read

Comment: @DanielMizerski That's no need to be rude. Everyone started to code once and had "stupid" questions.

Comment: what program can i use if i want to create slideimages or anything of that sort? i don't really understand all of the basics yet but i would like to focus on this task first.

Comment: @TobiasGlaus our new friend now know how funny his answer was. I originally written something similar to you, but deleted after update of comments. I badly wanted to write something nonconstructive.

Comment: @souzouker Could you tell me how it have to behave? Without technical details. I do not understand "need to be 2 image separatly or 1 merged picture"

Comment: @danielMizerski , i would like to know if both of the pictures need to be either left out respectively or sided together, like, merging 2 .png files into 1 .png file and you can see both of them sided together

Comment: @souzouker https://www.kirupa.com/html5/slide_image_hover_using_css3.htm ?

Comment: @souzouker Both is possible, but having 2 separate images is easier to handle. So would you like to have controls (like arrows to navigate to the next/previous image)?

Comment: @danielmizerski to be honest, i did watch this video and this site before asking my question ^^ , i was totally lost since the command he use for himself to create a "mouse hover slide image" as for your question tobias, i was trying to create a mouse hover image

Comment: @souzouker So if I get you right, you want to create something similar to [this](https://codepen.io/fixcl/pen/BImgA) ?

Comment: @souzouker I prepared very simple example to do simmiliar thing without JS. Check if that is what you want to do https://codepen.io/Duelsik/pen/BZWWmy

Comment: @danielmizerski yes this is what i wanted to know , thank you Daniel, and thank you Tobias too ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not fully sure what you're asking but is this what you're wanting? If so you're more interested in transitions or animations, hover within the blue border

https://jsfiddle.net/gevfeqk9/24/

```
  .college  {
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    }

  .college .image-1{
      transform: translate(-280px,0);
      transition: transform 1s ease-in-out 0s;
   }
   .college .image-2{
      transform: translate(-560px,0);
      transition: transform 1s ease-in-out 0s;
   }
  .college:hover .image-1,.college:hover .image-2{
    transform: translate(0,0);
   }
```

Comment: that is what i was looking for , thank you alexis, and thank you all for your help i learned alot of different sites that im gonna experiment for myself later ^^ .